# ElasticSearch 0.17.9 - 400 Bad Request on Windows Server 2008 R2 x64

Tags: windows-7, elasticsearch

I'm attempting to get ElasticSearch going. I downloaded ES 0.17.9 as well as elasticsearch-head. I'm using JDK 1.7.0.

I start the ES server with no errors, then using es-head, I've successfully connected to it (http://localhost:9200). Cluster info/node info all that overview stuff works fine. However, when I go to "Any Request" and try to do a PUT, it fails with a "400 bad request". The request is to http://localhost:9200/ with path PAFRetail/indextypes/1 and data: {"test":"test"}

Cluster info/node info looks like this:

```
{ 
cluster_name: elasticsearch 
nodes: { 
uQT1ZhL_SnedSdGOvUL0mQ: { 
name: Aardwolf 
indices: { 
size: 0b 
size_in_bytes: 0 
docs: { 
num_docs: 0 
} 

cache: { 
field_evictions: 0 
field_size: 0b 
field_size_in_bytes: 0 
filter_count: 0 
filter_evictions: 0 
filter_size: 0b 
filter_size_in_bytes: 0 
} 

merges: { 
current: 0 
total: 0 
total_time: 0s 
total_time_in_millis: 0 
} 
} 

os: { 
timestamp: 1319478468512 
uptime: 271 hours, 18 minutes and 54 seconds 
uptime_in_millis: 976734000 
load_average: [ ] 
cpu: { 
sys: 1 
user: 3 
idle: 94 
} 

mem: { 
free: 2.7gb 
free_in_bytes: 2921869312 
used: 5.2gb 
used_in_bytes: 5662928896 
free_percent: 47 
used_percent: 52 
actual_free: 3.7gb 
actual_free_in_bytes: 4035424256 
actual_used: 4.2gb 
actual_used_in_bytes: 4549373952 
} 

swap: { 
used: 5.3gb 
used_in_bytes: 5776781312 
free: 18.2gb 
free_in_bytes: 19583340544 
} 
} 

process: { 
timestamp: 1319478468517 
open_file_descriptors: -1 
cpu: { 
percent: 0 
sys: 592 milliseconds 
sys_in_millis: 592 
user: 3 seconds and 213 milliseconds 
user_in_millis: 3213 
total: 3 seconds and 805 milliseconds 
total_in_millis: 3805 
} 

mem: { 
resident: 133.5mb 
resident_in_bytes: 140062720 
share: -1b 
share_in_bytes: -1 
total_virtual: 1.3gb 
total_virtual_in_bytes: 1421873152 
} 
} 

jvm: { 
timestamp: 1319478468521 
uptime: 11 minutes, 48 seconds and 84 milliseconds 
uptime_in_millis: 708084 
mem: { 
heap_used: 35.7mb 
heap_used_in_bytes: 37529328 
heap_committed: 247.5mb 
heap_committed_in_bytes: 259522560 
non_heap_used: 21.2mb 
non_heap_used_in_bytes: 22253880 
non_heap_committed: 23.1mb 
non_heap_committed_in_bytes: 24313856 
} 

threads: { 
count: 31 
peak_count: 33 
} 

gc: { 
collection_count: 1 
collection_time: 36 milliseconds 
collection_time_in_millis: 36 
collectors: { 
ParNew: { 
collection_count: 1 
collection_time: 36 milliseconds 
collection_time_in_millis: 36 
} 

ConcurrentMarkSweep: { 
collection_count: 0 
collection_time: 0 milliseconds 
collection_time_in_millis: 0 
} 
} 
} 
} 

network: { 
tcp: { 
active_opens: 31054 
passive_opens: 2985 
curr_estab: 70 
in_segs: 3066040425 
out_segs: 3067744188 
retrans_segs: 7917 
estab_resets: 2809 
attempt_fails: 48 
in_errs: 0 
out_rsts: 3474 
} 
} 

transport: { 
server_open: 7 
} 

http: { 
server_open: 1 
} 
} 
} 
}
```

I also set up debug logging and get this:

```
E:\ElasticSearch\elasticsearch-0.17.9\bin>"C:\Program Files\Java 
\jdk1.7.0\bin\java"  -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Xss128k -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX: 
+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 
 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1 -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX: 
+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError  - 
Delasticsearch -Des-foreground=yes -Des.path.home="E:\ElasticSear 
ch\elasticsearch-0.17.9" -cp ";E:\ElasticSearch\elasticsearch-0.17.9/ 
lib/*;E:\ElasticSearch\elasticsearch-0.17.9/lib/sigar/*" 
"org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.ElasticSearch" 
[2011-10-24 10:36:00,812][INFO ][node                     ] [Aardwolf] 
{elasticsearch/0.17.9}[46508]: initializing ... 
[2011-10-24 10:36:00,820][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Aardwolf] 
loaded [], sites [] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:01,643][DEBUG][cache.memory             ] [Aardwolf] 
using bytebuffer cache with small_buffer_size [1kb], large_buffer_size 
[1mb], small_cache_size [10mb], large_cache_size [500mb], 
direct [true] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:01,657][DEBUG][threadpool               ] [Aardwolf] 
creating thread_pool [cached], type [cached], keep_alive [30s] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:01,659][DEBUG][threadpool               ] [Aardwolf] 
creating thread_pool [index], type [cached], keep_alive [5m] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:01,659][DEBUG][threadpool               ] [Aardwolf] 
creating thread_pool [search], type [cached], keep_alive [5m] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:01,660][DEBUG][threadpool               ] [Aardwolf] 
creating thread_pool [percolate], type [cached], keep_alive [5m] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:01,661][DEBUG][threadpool               ] [Aardwolf] 
creating thread_pool [management], type [scaling], min [1], size [20], 
keep_alive [5m] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:01,663][DEBUG][threadpool               ] [Aardwolf] 
creating thread_pool [merge], type [scaling], min [1], size [20], 
keep_alive [5m] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:01,664][DEBUG][threadpool               ] [Aardwolf] 
creating thread_pool [snapshot], type [scaling], min [1], size [40], 
keep_alive [5m] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:01,671][DEBUG][transport.netty          ] [Aardwolf] 
using worker_count[16], port[9300-9400], bind_host[null], 
publish_host[null], compress[false], connect_timeout[30s], 
connections_ 
per_node[2/4/1] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:01,682][DEBUG][discovery.zen.ping.multicast] 
[Aardwolf] using group [224.2.2.4], with port [54328], ttl [3], and 
address [null] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:01,687][DEBUG][discovery.zen.ping.unicast] 
[Aardwolf] using initial hosts [], with concurrent_connects [10] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:01,688][DEBUG][discovery.zen            ] [Aardwolf] 
using ping.timeout [3s] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:01,690][DEBUG][discovery.zen.fd         ] [Aardwolf] 
[master] uses ping_interval [1s], ping_timeout [30s], ping_retries [3] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:01,693][DEBUG][discovery.zen.fd         ] [Aardwolf] 
[node  ] uses ping_interval [1s], ping_timeout [30s], ping_retries [3] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:01,720][DEBUG][env                      ] [Aardwolf] 
using node location [E:\ElasticSearch\elasticsearch-0.17.9\data 
\elasticsearch\nodes\0], local_node_id [0] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:01,908][DEBUG][cluster.routing.allocation] 
[Aardwolf] using node_concurrent_recoveries [2], 
node_initial_primaries_recoveries [4] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:01,909][DEBUG][cluster.routing.allocation] 
[Aardwolf] using [allow_rebalance] with [indices_all_active] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:01,909][DEBUG][cluster.routing.allocation] 
[Aardwolf] using [cluster_concurrent_rebalance] with [2] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:01,912][DEBUG][gateway.local            ] [Aardwolf] 
using initial_shards [quorum], list_timeout [30s] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:01,936][DEBUG][monitor.jvm              ] [Aardwolf] 
enabled [false], last_gc_enabled [false], interval [1s], gc_threshold 
[5s] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:02,461][DEBUG][monitor.os               ] [Aardwolf] 
Using probe [org.elasticsearch.monitor.os.SigarOsProbe@60e70884] with 
refresh_interval [1s] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:02,504][DEBUG][monitor.process          ] [Aardwolf] 
Using probe 
[org.elasticsearch.monitor.process.SigarProcessProbe@49acd265] with 
refresh_interval [1s] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:02,507][DEBUG][monitor.jvm              ] [Aardwolf] 
Using refresh_interval [1s] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:02,508][DEBUG][monitor.network          ] [Aardwolf] 
Using probe 
[org.elasticsearch.monitor.network.SigarNetworkProbe@5c0273e1] with 
refresh_interval [5s] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:02,689][DEBUG][monitor.network          ] [Aardwolf] 
net_info 
host [Apollo] 
lo      display_name [Software Loopback Interface 1] 
                address [/127.0.0.1] [/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] 
                mtu [-1] multicast [true] ptp [false] loopback [true] 
up [true] virtual [false] 
net0    display_name [WAN Miniport (PPTP)] 
                address 
                mtu [-1] multicast [true] ptp [false] loopback [false] 
up [false] virtual [false] 
net1    display_name [WAN Miniport (SSTP)] 
                address 
                mtu [-1] multicast [true] ptp [false] loopback [false] 
up [false] virtual [false] 
net2    display_name [WAN Miniport (L2TP)] 
                address 
                mtu [-1] multicast [true] ptp [false] loopback [false] 
up [false] virtual [false] 
eth0    display_name [WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)] 
                address 
                mtu [-1] multicast [true] ptp [false] loopback [false] 
up [false] virtual [false] 
eth1    display_name [WAN Miniport (IP)] 
                address 
                mtu [-1] multicast [true] ptp [false] loopback [false] 
up [false] virtual [false] 
eth2    display_name [WAN Miniport (IPv6)] 
                address 
                mtu [-1] multicast [true] ptp [false] loopback [false] 
up [false] virtual [false] 
ppp0    display_name [WAN Miniport (PPPOE)] 
                address 
                mtu [-1] multicast [true] ptp [false] loopback [false] 
up [false] virtual [false] 
ppp1    display_name [RAS Async Adapter] 
                address 
                mtu [-1] multicast [true] ptp [false] loopback [false] 
up [false] virtual [false] 
eth3    display_name [Intel(R) PRO/1000 PT Dual Port Network 
Connection] 
                address 
                mtu [-1] multicast [true] ptp [false] loopback [false] 
up [false] virtual [false] 
eth4    display_name [Intel(R) PRO/1000 PT Dual Port Network 
Connection #2] 
                address 
                mtu [-1] multicast [true] ptp [false] loopback [false] 
up [false] virtual [false] 
eth5    display_name [Intel(R) PRO/1000 EB Network Connection with I/O 
Acceleration] 
                address [/10.44.0.16] [/fe80:0:0:0:5071:1913:9d81:8cee 
%12] 
                mtu [1500] multicast [true] ptp [false] loopback 
[false] up [true] virtual [false] 
eth6    display_name [Intel(R) PRO/1000 EB Network Connection with I/O 
Acceleration #2] 
                address 
                mtu [-1] multicast [true] ptp [false] loopback [false] 
up [false] virtual [false] 
net3    display_name [Microsoft ISATAP Adapter] 
                address [/fe80:0:0:0:0:5efe:a2c:10%14] 
                mtu [1280] multicast [false] ptp [true] loopback 
[false] up [false] virtual [false] 
net4    display_name [Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface] 
                address [/2001:0:4137:9e76:1c93:19dc:f5d3:ffef] [/ 
fe80:0:0:0:1c93:19dc:f5d3:ffef%15] 
                mtu [1280] multicast [false] ptp [true] loopback 
[false] up [true] virtual [false] 
net5    display_name [WAN Miniport (IKEv2)] 
                address 
                mtu [-1] multicast [true] ptp [false] loopback [false] 
up [false] virtual [false] 
eth7    display_name [Intel(R) PRO/1000 EB Network Connection with I/O 
Acceleration-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000] 
                address 
                mtu [-1] multicast [true] ptp [false] loopback [false] 
up [false] virtual [false] 
eth8    display_name [Intel(R) PRO/1000 EB Network Connection with I/O 
Acceleration-WFP LightWeight Filter-0000] 
                address 
                mtu [-1] multicast [true] ptp [false] loopback [false] 
up [false] virtual [false] 
eth9    display_name [WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)-QoS Packet 
Scheduler-0000] 
                address 
                mtu [-1] multicast [true] ptp [false] loopback [false] 
up [false] virtual [false] 
eth10   display_name [WAN Miniport (IP)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000] 
                address 
                mtu [-1] multicast [true] ptp [false] loopback [false] 
up [false] virtual [false] 
eth11   display_name [WAN Miniport (IPv6)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000] 
                address 
                mtu [-1] multicast [true] ptp [false] loopback [false] 
up [false] virtual [false] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:02,823][DEBUG][http.netty               ] [Aardwolf] 
using max_chunk_size[8kb], max_header_size[8kb], 
max_initial_line_length[4kb], max_content_length[100mb] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:02,828][DEBUG][index.shard.recovery     ] [Aardwolf] 
using concurrent_streams [5], file_chunk_size [100kb], translog_size 
[100kb], translog_ops [1000], and compress [true] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:02,831][DEBUG][indices.memory           ] [Aardwolf] 
using index_buffer_size [98.9mb], with min_shard_index_buffer_size 
[4mb], max_shard_index_buffer_size [512mb], shard_inactive_tim 
e [30m] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:02,841][DEBUG][indices.cache.filter     ] [Aardwolf] 
using [node] filter cache with size [197.9mb] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:02,892][INFO ][node                     ] [Aardwolf] 
{elasticsearch/0.17.9}[46508]: initialized 
[2011-10-24 10:36:02,893][INFO ][node                     ] [Aardwolf] 
{elasticsearch/0.17.9}[46508]: starting ... 
[2011-10-24 10:36:02,913][DEBUG] 
[netty.channel.socket.nio.NioProviderMetadata] Using the autodetected 
NIO constraint level: 0 
[2011-10-24 10:36:02,963][DEBUG][transport.netty          ] [Aardwolf] 
Bound to address [/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:03,020][INFO ][transport                ] [Aardwolf] 
bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/ 
10.44.0.16:9300]} 
[2011-10-24 10:36:06,183][DEBUG][discovery.zen            ] [Aardwolf] 
ping responses: {none} 
[2011-10-24 10:36:06,187][DEBUG][cluster.service          ] [Aardwolf] 
processing [zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)]: execute 
[2011-10-24 10:36:06,188][DEBUG][cluster.service          ] [Aardwolf] 
cluster state updated, version [1], source [zen-disco-join 
(elected_as_master)] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:06,190][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Aardwolf] 
new_master [Aardwolf][uQT1ZhL_SnedSdGOvUL0mQ][inet[/10.44.0.16:9300]], 
reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master) 
[2011-10-24 10:36:06,223][DEBUG][transport.netty          ] [Aardwolf] 
Connected to node [[Aardwolf][uQT1ZhL_SnedSdGOvUL0mQ][inet[/ 
10.44.0.16:9300]]] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:06,228][DEBUG][river.cluster            ] [Aardwolf] 
processing [reroute_rivers_node_changed]: execute 
[2011-10-24 10:36:06,228][INFO ][discovery                ] [Aardwolf] 
elasticsearch/uQT1ZhL_SnedSdGOvUL0mQ 
[2011-10-24 10:36:06,228][DEBUG][cluster.service          ] [Aardwolf] 
processing [zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)]: done applying updated 
cluster_state 
[2011-10-24 10:36:06,230][DEBUG][river.cluster            ] [Aardwolf] 
processing [reroute_rivers_node_changed]: no change in cluster_state 
[2011-10-24 10:36:06,243][DEBUG][gateway.local            ] [Aardwolf] 
elected state from [[Aardwolf][uQT1ZhL_SnedSdGOvUL0mQ][inet[/ 
10.44.0.16:9300]]] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:06,244][DEBUG][cluster.service          ] [Aardwolf] 
processing [local-gateway-elected-state]: execute 
[2011-10-24 10:36:06,247][DEBUG][cluster.service          ] [Aardwolf] 
cluster state updated, version [8], source [local-gateway-elected- 
state] 
[2011-10-24 10:36:06,248][DEBUG][river.cluster            ] [Aardwolf] 
processing [reroute_rivers_node_changed]: execute 
[2011-10-24 10:36:06,248][DEBUG][river.cluster            ] [Aardwolf] 
processing [reroute_rivers_node_changed]: no change in cluster_state 
[2011-10-24 10:36:06,252][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Aardwolf] 
recovered [0] indices into cluster_state 
[2011-10-24 10:36:06,253][DEBUG][cluster.service          ] [Aardwolf] 
processing [local-gateway-elected-state]: done applying updated 
cluster_state 
[2011-10-24 10:36:06,311][INFO ][http                     ] [Aardwolf] 
bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/ 
10.44.0.16:9200]} 
[2011-10-24 10:36:06,312][INFO ][node                     ] [Aardwolf] 
{elasticsearch/0.17.9}[46508]: started 
[2011-10-24 10:36:16,227][DEBUG][cluster.service          ] [Aardwolf] 
processing [routing-table-updater]: execute 
[2011-10-24 10:36:16,228][DEBUG][cluster.service          ] [Aardwolf] 
processing [routing-table-updater]: no change in cluster_state 
[2011-10-24 10:36:16,811][DEBUG][cluster.service          ] [Aardwolf] 
processing [create-index [PAFRetail], cause [auto(index api)]]: 
execute 
[2011-10-24 10:36:16,812][DEBUG][cluster.service          ] [Aardwolf] 
processing [create-index [PAFRetail], cause [auto(index api)]]: no 
change in cluster_state
```

I notice there are no "action" logs so it seems like it's dying earlier... any ideas?

Thanks!
-Tim

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out - apparently ElasticSearch doesn't like it when the index has uppercase letters in it. As soon as I changed "PAFRetail" to "pafretail", everything worked fine.

Thanks for looking!
-Tim